# How to repeat scroll image in a slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

My question how can I scroll thumb images endless? I mean when I click on right point images (>) should be scroll left and repeat again from first image and same with right pointer.

I has been success to scroll image but in scroll end image not scroll. and i want to scroll endless(means should be repeat again).

Please help.

**Thank you in advance.**

```js
function slider(action){

  if(action == 'next'){
     var leftPos = $('#bx-pager').scrollLeft();
    $("#bx-pager").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos - 50}, 500);
  } else {
    var leftPos = $('#bx-pager').scrollLeft();
    $("#bx-pager").animate({scrollLeft: leftPos + 50}, 500);
  }

}
```

```css
.slideWrap{position: relative;height: 50px;width:300px;overflow:hidden}
.slideWrap span{background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);height: 100%;position: absolute;top:0px;right: 0;z-index: 1;}
.slideWrap span i{color: #fff;height:50px;padding: 15px 2px}
.slideWrap span i:hover{color: #f2822e}
span#moveNext {}
span#movePrev{left: 0;right: auto;}

#bx-pager ul {padding: 0;margin: 0;width: 400px;list-style:none}
#bx-pager ul li{float: left}
#bx-pager ul li a img{height: 50px;width: 50px;border:3px solid #333;margin:2.5%}
```

```html
<script src="https://github.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/blob/master/src/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="slideWrap">
                                            <span id="moveNext"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="slider('next')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a></span>
                                                <div id="bx-pager">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="0" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="3" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="1" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="3" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="2" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                        <li><a data-slide-index="3" href=""><img src="http://www.ucl.ac.uk/news/news-articles/1213/muscle-fibres-heart.jpg" /></a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </div>
                                            <span id="movePrev" > <a  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="slider('prev')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></span>
                                            </div>
```

Comment: if you are using bxslider, why dont you give the option "default:true;"  as mentioned in the page http://bxslider.com/options#infiniteLoop ?

Comment: @sai please check this link http://54.160.13.227/solar/19_Sale_View_B_details.html then you know the actual problem.

Comment: I hope you are getting me.

Comment: I am sorry i am not exactly understanding you. lets say you have 10 thumb images in your slider, you want progress from 1 through 10 on the right arrow and after you reach 10, thumb 1 should be displayed?

Comment: Its not matter, how many images in bottom side, i just want images scrolling in a loop (means not end on a particular point). i am talking about bottom slider which you can see on link or see in snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all of you for your effort, but I get correct answer.

```
function slider() {
    var item_width = $('#bx-pager ul li').width(); 
    var left_value = item_width * (-1); 


        var left_indent = parseInt($('#bx-pager ul').css('left')) - item_width;

        $('#bx-pager ul ').animate({'left' : left_indent}, 100, function () {
            $('#bx-pager ul li:last').after($('#bx-pager ul li:first'));                  
            $('#bx-pager ul').css({'left' : left_value});

        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach to that would be:
1. On event being 'next': remove the first child from the ul and add it to the end of the ul tag.
2. On click of 'previous': remove the last child from the ul and add it to the front of the ul.

Use .children to get the children and then access the 0th or the chilren.length - 1th child & play with it

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was the CSS3 transitions and adding useCSS: false forces bxslider to use jQuery for the transitions instead of CSS.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
     $('.bxslider').bxSlider({

         auto: true,
         autoControls: false,
         controls: false,
         pause: 4000,
         infiniteLoop: true,
         mode: 'horizontal',
         autoDirection: 'next',
         responsive: true,
         preloadImages: 'all',
         minSlides: 2,
         autoDelay: 0,
         randomStart: false,
         pager: false,
         moveSlideQty: 1,
         useCSS: false,
           });
         });
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to use plugin for this task,
I hope this plugin help you, http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/